# Can I directly process buffer data using Sharp in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, image-processing, sharp

I get buffer data to my program from external and I want to process buffer data and send it as a buffer also.
So I don't want to convert buffer into an image.
How can I do this?

I try this way but it not work.

```
const process = await sharp(incoming_buffer_data).grayscale();
```

`fs.writeFileSync('test.jpg', process);` // I am using this for testing. Allways I am getting worng image format as an error

Comment: Very, very, very bad! you are overriding the global `process` variable!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming `incoming_buffer_data` is indeed a buffer and has a supported image format.

You can either get the output as buffer, and send it to `fs.writeFileSync()` like you tried to do

```
const buffer = await sharp(incoming_buffer_data).grayscale().toBuffer();
fs.writeFileSync('test.jpg', buffer);
```

Or you can write it to a file directly

```
await sharp(incoming_buffer_data).grayscale().toFile('test.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Working snippet.

```js
sharp(buffer)
  .greyscale()
  .toFile('file.png', (err, info) => {
    // file is stored as file.png in current directory
})
```

You can even do other thing as well like resizing

```js
sharp(buffer)
  .greyscale()
  .resize(512,512,{fit:'contain'})
  .toFile('file.png', (err, info) => {
    // file is stored as file.png in current directory
})
```